# Import Search engine from Chrome into Microsoft Chromium Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, chromium

When I first launched Microsoft Chromium Edge, I have imported the data from Chrome. I got my bookmarks and others things but not my custom "Search engines".

How can I import my Search engine from Chrome into Microsoft Chromium Edge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how I have done it using the open source [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/).

**⚠ You will need to close the Edge browser so Copy this answer in a text. ⚠**

○ Download and install `DB Browser for SQLite`

○ Copy Chrome Web Data

- Go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`
- Copy the file `Web Data` (no extension) to your desktop and rename it `Chrome Web Data`
- Open `Chrome Web Data` with `DB browser for SQLite` (the file has no extension but it's an `.sqlite`): ex right-click > open with  or double click the file and choose `DB browser for SQLite`

○ Copy Edge Web Data

- Close Edge
- Go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Edge Dev\User Data\Default`
- Copy the file `Edge Web Data` on desktop, rename the original `Edge Web Data` (ex: `Edge Web Data`) and rename the copied to `Edge Web Data`
- Open `Edge Web Data` in `DB browser for SQLite`

○ Comparing ID from the Keywords tables

- In `Chrome Web Data`, go to `Browse Data tab`, and select the table `Keywords`
- Click on ID header to sort the entries by ID
- Do the last 2 steps with `Edge Web Data`, too
- Compare the IDS : if some IDs are present in the 2 databases, you will need to change the ID in the `Chrome Web Data` into ID that aren't used in `Edge Web Data`. To do that you need to click on each ID in `Chrome Web Data`, go to the `edit database cell pane` (cf view-), change the number and click save

○ Export Keywords table from Chrome Web Data

- In `Chrome Web Data`, go to menu file>export>Database to SQL file
- Select only the table `Keywords` and click save (leave "keep column name" and "Multiple row" unchecked and keep "Export everything" and "Keep old schema")

○ Import in Edge

- In `Edge Web Data`, go to menu file>import >Database from SQL file
- Choose "Keywords.sql" that you have just exported.
- Answer No to "do you want to create..." (we want to import already existing table). Check the table `Keywords` and save
- Move `Edge Web Data` into `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Local\Microsoft\Edge Dev\User Data\Default` and rename it `Web Data`
- Open Edge

If you have added as a search engines some address like `chrome://extensions/`, Edge will redirect them automatically to`edge://extensions/`. If you like when things are tidy, you can update all the `chrome://` links, but if you don't do that, it will still work.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the answer of @MagTun is correct but now the keywords table in Edge has 23 columns instead of 22 in Chrome.

You need to add `created_from_play_api` INTEGER DEFAULT 0 column to the exported Sql Script of `Web Data.Keywords` table of Chrome.

And Be careful that if you have multiple profiles to point to on the correct `Web Data` file.

Comment: hi, how could I add or insert a column using `DB Browser for SQLite` in Ubuntu please. I can't seem to find any option to add or insert that 23rd column for `created_from_play_api`. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` and create a **backup copy** for the ***`Web Data`*** file.
2. Go to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default` and do the same.
3. **Close** the **Browser** you want to import data (and its **Background Processes**)
4. Copy and paste the ***`Web Data`*** file from one browser (**exporting**) into the desired browser (**importing**)
5. Reopen your Browser to check if everything is alright. Otherwise, just copy and paste back the previous original ***`Web Data`*** file.

Comment: Worked for me on Edge Version 118.0.2088.69 (Official build) (64-bit)